# Performance monitor always showing 100%

Tags: c#

While following a video on how to make a performance monitor, I ran into a bug. It only ever shows a 100% CPU load even when every other monitoring app I have says its only at idle 5%.

Heres the code

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
using System.Diagnostics;    
using System.Threading;    
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace CPU
{

    class Program
    {

        private static SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Cpu messages
            List<string> cpumaxedOutMessages = new List<string>();

            cpumaxedOutMessages.Add("Warning CPU FULL LOAD");
            cpumaxedOutMessages.Add("CPU RUNNING AT 100% SLOW DOWN");
            cpumaxedOutMessages.Add("CPU IS GOING AROUND IN CIRCLES");
            cpumaxedOutMessages.Add("SOVIET MISSILE LAUNCH, WAIT. ITS NOT, I JUST AM OVERHEATING FROM BEING AT 100% ALL THE TIME!");
            cpumaxedOutMessages.Add("DEF CON 1 REACHED");

            Random rand = new Random();

            //Greets user
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            Console.WriteLine("Performance Monitor");
            synth.Speak("Welcome to the Performance Monitor");
            # region My PerfMonitor

            //This pulls CPU Cpde in %
            PerformanceCounter perfCpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
            perfCpuCount.NextValue();
            //Mem count
            PerformanceCounter perfMemCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
            perfMemCount.NextValue();
            //Up time (In Sec)
            PerformanceCounter perfUptimeCount = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
            perfUptimeCount.NextValue();


            TimeSpan uptimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(perfUptimeCount.NextValue());
            string systemUpTimeMessage = string.Format("The current System up time is {0} days {1} Hours {2} Minutes {3} Seconds",
            (int)uptimeSpan.TotalDays,
            (int)uptimeSpan.Hours,
            (int)uptimeSpan.Minutes,
            (int)uptimeSpan.Seconds
            );

            int speechSpeed = 1;

            //Tell user what uptime is
            Speak(systemUpTimeMessage, VoiceGender.Female, 3);


            //Infinite Loop
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                //Every 1 Second Prints CPU Load

                //Gets current Perf Values
                int currentCpuPercentage = (int)perfCpuCount.NextValue();
                int currentAvailableMemory = (int)perfMemCount.NextValue();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("CPU Load        : {0}%", currentCpuPercentage);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine("Available Memory: {0}MB", currentAvailableMemory);


                if (currentCpuPercentage > 80)
                {
                    if (currentCpuPercentage == 100)
                    {                     
                        string cpuLoadVocalMessage = cpumaxedOutMessages[rand.Next(5)];
                        Speak(cpuLoadVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Male, speechSpeed);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        string cpuLoadVocalMessage = String.Format("The current Cpu Load is {0} Percent", currentCpuPercentage);
                        Speak(cpuLoadVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Female, 3);
                    }

                 //Memory

                    if (currentAvailableMemory > 1024)
                    {
                       string memAvailableVocalMessage = String.Format("You currently have {0} Megabytes of memory available", currentAvailableMemory);
                       Speak(memAvailableVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Male ,5 );
                    }
                    else


                    Thread.Sleep(1000);


                } //End of loop
            }
        }
        //speaks with a selcted Voice
        public static void Speak(string message, VoiceGender voiceGender)
        {
            synth.SelectVoiceByHints(voiceGender);
            synth.Speak(message);
        }
        //speaks with selcted voice and function
        public static void Speak(string message, VoiceGender voiceGender, int rate)
        {
            synth.Rate = rate;
            Speak(message, voiceGender);
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is causing the 100% processing load. It should be like this:

```
while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                //Every 1 Second Prints CPU Load

                //Gets current Perf Values
                int currentCpuPercentage = (int)perfCpuCount.NextValue();
                int currentAvailableMemory = (int)perfMemCount.NextValue();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.WriteLine("CPU Load        : {0}%", currentCpuPercentage);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine("Available Memory: {0}MB", currentAvailableMemory);


                if (currentCpuPercentage > 80)
                {
                    if (currentCpuPercentage == 100)
                    {
                        string cpuLoadVocalMessage = cpumaxedOutMessages[rand.Next(5)];
                        Speak(cpuLoadVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Male, speechSpeed);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        string cpuLoadVocalMessage = String.Format("The current Cpu Load is {0} Percent", currentCpuPercentage);
                        Speak(cpuLoadVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Female, 3);
                    }

                    //Memory

                    if (currentAvailableMemory > 1024)
                    {
                        string memAvailableVocalMessage = String.Format("You currently have {0} Megabytes of memory available", currentAvailableMemory);
                        Speak(memAvailableVocalMessage, VoiceGender.Male, 5);
                    }





                } //End of loop
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //note that the sleep now gets called every update cycle
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something got lost somewhere around:

```
 else

 Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

The result is that the code rarely, if ever, waits 1 second. When `currentAvailableMemory <= 1024` it will wait.